# Passing custom parameter values or attributes to an error-page Servlet handler

Tags: java, servlets

I have declared an error-page in my web.xml to catch all exceptions.

somewhat like so...

```
<error-page>
   <location>/errorhandler</location>
<error-page>
```

I have a mapping in the web.xml for the same to servlet name "ErrorHandlerServlet".

So now, Somewhere in my application code where am throwing an error that is going to send me to the error-page handler, I want to be able to set my custom attributes or parameters so that later, I can retrieve them in my ErrorHandlerServlet. Just like I retrieve the other built in attributes like below:

```
String errorMessage = (String)request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

So basically, I also want to be able to call:

```
String myCustomAttributeValue = (String)request.getAttribute("my_attribute_name");
```

OR call:

```
String myCustomParamValue = request.getParameter("my_param_name");
```

.. and get my custom attribute values or parameter values that I added when the error was being thrown.

How do I pass these custom attributes/parameters? code examples will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest another approach. Have the data you need encapsulated inside the exception instance you throw. The exception instance will be available to your error handler and you can retrieve the data from within the exception object.

It will be easier to manage the data in the exception and wrap any other type of exception into your custom exception type and add the data you need, than to have the HTTP request object available everywhere you need to add this data (in a business class the HTTP request object has no place for example).

Comment: Bogdan, the place am throwing an error is inside a Servlet so I have access to the request/response objects. Though I have taken note of your suggestion. Waiting for more answers from others

Comment: Bogdan, decided to wrap all data I need in a custom exception object extending Throwable. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Set an attribute like how you set any other data

`request.setAttribute('err_key', 'your_value');`

or are you asking for something else ? You cannot set parameters directly.

Comment: ramp, not quite, was asking something else. I will go ahead and use Bogdan's suggestion. Works for me. thnx